# Do any passenger-carrying freighters connect Norway to North America through the Arctic?

Tags: freighter-travel, arctic

There are plenty of Trans-Atlantic freighters that carry passengers; perhaps it's the most popular crossing for freighter travel.  Some are listed at [freightercruises.com](https://www.freightercruises.com/voyages.php#transatlantic) or [freighter-travel.com](http://www.freighter-travel.com/travel-itineraries.html).  I've also found some north-west passage freighters, but they connect only [Greenland and North-America](https://www.freightercruises.com/seaworthy_news_1105.php).  Are there any passenger-carrying freighters that connect northern Norway with North-America (preferably a place in North America with onward public transportation) through the Arctic or the high north in general, rather than going south to France/UK/Ireland before crossing the Atlantic?

Comment: That would be amazing, I'd totally want to do that trip. Travel.SE meetup!

Answer (score 4):

I found an [interesting site](http://www.flightlesstravel.com/plan/cargo-ships/) that lists a lot of companies and sites that allows you to become a passenger on a freighter.  The thing is that there are no direct routes from Norway that I can find to anywhere in North America.

The best I was I able find was routes operated [Hamburg Sud](http://www.hamburgsued-frachtschiffreisen.de/hsr/en/freightertravel/freightertravel_1/freightertraveloverview.jsp) from Rotterdam to multiple ports in Norway and from Rotterdam to multiple places in the US.  There is also a different German Company [Rickmers-Linie](http://www.rickmers-linie.de/index.php) which operates through Hamburg and will let you again change ships to Scandinavia (Sweden and Finland) and that's about it.

Comment: Peculiar how the photo on the site shows a ship in a frozen sea.  Presumably between Sweden and Finland then.

Comment: Looks like it.  Ice is not that thick...