# From Canada to Norway, through the North Pole, is that possible?

Tags: canada, tours, routes, norway

I'm just wondering if is possible to pass from Canada to Europe through the North Pole.
It could be with a travel company (maybe more than one); I think it is going to be impossible by myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do any passenger-carrying freighters connect Norway to North America through the Arctic?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18460/do-any-passenger-carrying-freighters-connect-norway-to-north-america-through-the)

Comment: Or if not a duplicate certainly very related.

Comment: @gerrit: while global warming may soon allow you to reach the North Pole by ship, this is not yet the case.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Depends how literally OP means *the North Pole*.  Some people sloppily use this as a synonym for the larger Arctic Ocean.

Answer (score 9):

Using what kind of transportation? By plane, it's obviously no problem at all. Doing it by [submarine](http://www.whoi.edu/page.do?pid=66624) is possible but hiring one for this purpose is probably not.

A [British expedition](http://www.transglobe-expedition.org/page/the-arctic) in 1982 crossed the arctic (from Canada via the north pole to Svalbard) using snow mobiles, but due to the difficult terrain (the arctic is covered by pack ice, which means both ice ridges and water channels) it took them a very long time and required supplies delivered by airplane.

Nowadays, such expeditions are typically done using skis and drawing sleds that can double as boats, in order to be more nimble. [Reinhold Messner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhold_Messner) tried and failed to cross the Arctic that way in 1995. I couldn't find details about that expedition, only a hint that it failed early.

A [Belgian expedition](http://www.educapoles.org/news/news_detail/alain_and_dixie_are_back_in_belgium/) in 2007 crossed from Siberia to southern Greenland on skis and sleds, and going to Canada should not be more difficult, so that proves it can be done.

*However*, I think the real answer is "**If you have to ask, it is not possible for you**". Such expeditions require extreme physical fitness and experience. There are [companies that offer](http://www.northwinds-arctic.com/npski.html) north pole expeditions, but:

> Cost: 2 Expedition members: $150,000 per person Canadian
>
> [...]
>
> Prerequisites: Must be in excellent physical condition and in good health. Basic cross country ski skills and winter camping experience is required. We will ask you for a detailed resume of your health, physical fitness, skill level and previous expedition experience before accepting you on the expedition. You will also need evacuation insurance.

And that's for *a shorter, easier tour!* Actually crossing the Arctic is only realistically possible for people who have done similar feats before and know how to organize such a trip.